# behavior of control characters has changed in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: search, control-character

Before upgrading to ubuntu 20.04, the line

```
g/;/s//CTRL V CTRL M/
```

would replace the ; with a new line.

Now, in ubuntu 20.04 this string translates to

```
:g/;/s//^[[27;5;109~
```

which obviously doesn't have the desired outcome.

How would I get back to the old behavior of vi?

Comment: Are you sure this is not coming from your config? I'm on 20.10 and can't reproduce. I can't recall having this problem on 20.04 either.

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but you can write `:%s/;/\r` for the same effect

Comment: Hi @Biggybi thanks for trying.  Definitely not my config file, I've run this without any config file at all.     Was it clear from my question that when I wrote CTRL, I meant the control key, not literally CTRL?     Also, are you running VIM 8.1.    I can't reproduce with vim 8.0

Comment: @LeoSimon Clear enough for me! My Vim is up to date. Might be coming from your shell or terminal emulator.

Comment: This is a terminal issue. What terminal is this, what is your $TERM configuration? Does it happen with `vim --clean`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, You're right!   It is an `xterm` issue.   `$TERM` is set to `xterm`.  The problem doesn't arise when I use `x-terminal-emulator`.     It *does* happen with `xterm` when I use `vim --clean`.     This seems to suggest it's a bug in the `ubuntu 20.04` version of `xterm`.    I could go back to using the 18.04 version, but there's a shared library problem with this:  `error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5` and I'd rather not keep loading old libraries, obviously.     Any suggestions for a work-around?  @Biggybi, when you tried to replicate, were you  using `xterm`?

Comment: I just tried with `uxterm` and had the same problem.

Comment: I would try with an updated Vim first

Comment: Thanks very much  Christian, problem is fixed in `vim 8.2`     Could you make your recommendation an answer so I can accept it?