# :noesckeys in vim.basic giving anomalous behavior in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: replace

As reported in [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28776/behavior-of-control-characters-has-changed-in-ubuntu-20-04),
I've upgraded to ubuntu 20.04, and am seeing anomalous behavior in `vim.basic`

In addition to the one reported there, I'm now having problems with the `noesckeys` setting.
My setup is vanilla, with having turned off my `~/.vimrc` file.

When `noesckeys` is enabled, if I try to change `helloworld` to `helloWorld` by putting the cursor at the `w` and typing `rW`,
the string is changed to `helloWORLD`.    When I `:set esckeys`, I get the expected behavior.
Can anybody duplicate this in 20.04, and if so, explain it please?

Comment: as mentioned on your other post, this might be a terminal issue.

Comment: I resolved this problem by upgrading `vim` to 8.2